What is the relationship between sound frequency that generated by fan and the RPM of fan itself?
So I just bought high RPM external fan for laptop. It doesn't have sensor. So it's purely actuator device. Therefore the cheap measurement I can do, is using my phone microphone and open spectrogram capture app to capture sound frequency.
I saw some articles, there is relationship between fan and noise that produced. It measured by Blade Pass Frequency that calculating RPM and number of blades then returning frequency.
The market claims the fan has 4000 RPM. How do I verify the market claims? The product itself has 3 fans.


Can you verify whether my assumption is correct?
Based on spectrogram, it has 3 peaks. Here is my assumption: "The number of peaks represent number of fans". They are constant on their bands. The peak of frequencies are 598, 609, and 633 (hertz unit). Ofcourse it's imperfect on nano scale that every fans doesn't have exact equal value each other.
So, can I get the RPM estimation value of the fans?
Or at least, can I use this measurement as performance measurement in case of performance degradation? For example if the frequency is used to be 633 Hz, but in future it dropped to 550 Hz, it implies performance degradation.

So how many blades does each fan have ?

why don't you use a stroboscope app

As the fan blades rotate, they pass by a fixed point in space. Each blade passing this point creates a pressure pulse in the air due to its shape and motion. The pressure pulse generated by each blade passing the fixed point is a periodic event, occurring at a rate determined by the fan’s rotational speed. This periodicity results in a sound wave at the blade pass frequency (BPF).
Given BPF and number of fan blades, the fan rotational speed, measured in rotations per minute (RPM), is obtained as
$$
\textrm{RPM} = \frac{60\times\textrm{BPF}}{\textrm{Number of Blades}}
$$
Yes, measuring the rotational speed of a fan (RPM) over time can be deemed a criterion for assessing fan quality, although it is just one of several factors to consider.
A high-quality fan should maintain a consistent RPM over time, as fluctuations could indicate issues with the motor or bearings. The RPM of a fan directly affects its airflow and cooling capacity. RPM is related to the noise level of the fan. Higher RPMs generally result in more noise, so monitoring RPM can help assess the fan’s noise characteristics and identify any abnormal or excessive noise levels.
The BPF noise is often a significant component of the overall noise produced by the fan, especially at lower frequencies. It can contribute to a tonal quality in the noise, which can be more noticeable or annoying than broadband noise.

That's correct for the fundamental of the noise but blades often create turbulent flow (instead of laminar flow) which has a complicated harmonic spectrum and also a fair bit of non-harmonic components.
